# Transfer ownership of a Google Drive directory to another user

Tags: google-drive-api

When i transfer the ownership of a Google Drive directory to another user it doesn't transfer the ownership of its children directories/files.

I could transfer all the files recursively, but i feel it's a too complicated solution and i'm also afraid that in case of hundreds of files i might get an API limit error.

The [documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/batch) that explains batch requests says it's possible, but the NodeJS example i'm using doesn't seem to really make a batch request, but only calls the same API after a previous call has succeeded.

Isn't there a possible trick i could use to transfer a directory and children and the next generations on a single call?

Answer (score 1):

You can try [searching](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/search-parameters) all files with parent of that directory.

```
'1234567' in parents
```

Then add it in the batch request.

```
{   
    var batch = new googleBatch();
    batch.setAuth(authClient.gapi.token);
    
    batch.add({
        method: 'PUT',
        fileId: myId,
        addParents: addParents.join(','),
        removeParents: removeParents.join(','),
        fields: ['title', 'id', 'parents'].join(',')
    });
    
    batch.add({
        method: 'PUT',
        fileId: myId,
        body: {
            title: 'myNewTitle'
        }
    });
    
    batch.exec(function(errors, responses){
        // your stuff
    });
    
}
```

Edit the code that will match what you want to achieve. See additional information in this [link](https://github.com/blackrabbit99/google-drive-batch-requests).

> Note: A set of **n** requests batched together counts toward your usage limit as **n** requests, not as one request. The batch request is taken apart into a set of requests before processing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That's an interesting solution.
Unfortunately i won't be able to verify it, because i went into a different approach of acquiring user permission so my server will upload the files directly into his google drive account instead of transferring the ownership.

I came to the conclusion that it's a better way, because even if i would manage to make a batch request the problem would be that the new owner would receive hundreds of email notifications that cannot be disabled when transferring ownership and the other problem is that all the files would be copied to the root folder of the new owner